# Angular 2 Hidden Divs still show spacing

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I've got a really long form and want to show pieces of the form based on what section the user clicked.  I don't want to use *ngIf because it removes elements from the Dom and have a form validator that needs to read the entire template whole.

Right now I am hiding divs using this `<div class="row social-media"
[hidden]="navToggleIndex!=1">` but when I switch to a new section, the spacing of rows is still there.  So I get blank space until the next set of visible divs/rows. How can I also hide the spacing? *ngIf removes spacing but causes the problem above.

Comment: `visibility: hidden` doesn't remove the element from the DOM, so all positional styling is still present. I'm guessing you have other rules affecting that element? Does it have any `margin` or `padding` or `line-height`? With `class="row"`, I'm guessing you're using some sort of framework?

Comment: Looks like it is keeping the hidden row formats.  Is there an easy way I can hide the row formatting as well? Using Bootstrap 3.3.7 in Angular CLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
<div class="row social-media" [ngClass]="{ 'hide': navToggleIndex!=1 }">
```

And I'm not sure which validation library you currently used.
But If it's jQuery Validator, you must put this options.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    ignore: []
});
```

To prevent jQuery Validator ignores hidden elements.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!